# Elasticsearch Mapping and Field Type

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello Elasticsearch Gurus out there.

Given the following index and doctype:
   localhost:9200/myindex/mydoctype

I currently have this index definition:

```
{
  "myindex": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "mydoctype": {
        "properties": {
          "theNumber": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "theString": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1487158714808",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "version": {
          "created": "1070599"
        },
        "uuid": "cm2OtivhTO-RjuZPeHvL1w"
      }
    },
    "warmers": {}
  }
}
```

---

And I was able to add this document:

```
{
    "theNumber" : 0,
    "theString" : "zero"
}
```

---

But what I wasn't expecting, is that, I am also able to add this document:

```
{
    "theNumber" : 3.1418,
    "theString" : 3,
    "fiefoe" : "fiefoe"
}
```

... where the field types doesn't match.
As well as there is a new field/column introduced.
I wasn't expecting this kind of behaviour because of the Mappings I have defined for my index.

Does this have something to do with Elasticsearch being schema-less?
Is it possible to set Elasticsearch to accept only those types and fields for every document added for this index?
Is this how elasticsearch mapping work in the first place? (maybe I didn't know hehehe)

Thanks =)

Answer (score 6):

Elasticsearch uses dynamic mapping, so when it finds a field that doesn't exist in the mapping, it tries to index it by guessing its type.
What you can do it to disable this behavior using `dynamic: false` in the mapping on the root object. In this case ElasticSearch will ignore the unmapped field.

```
 {
  "myindex": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
        "mydoctype": {
        "dynamic": false, <-----

        "properties": {
          "theNumber": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "theString": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1487158714808",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "version": {
          "created": "1070599"
        },
        "uuid": "cm2OtivhTO-RjuZPeHvL1w"
      }
    },
    "warmers": {}
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `dynamic:strict` if you want to throw an exception when an unmapped field is trying to be indexed.

The documentation for this is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/dynamic-mapping.html).

Comment: @ArtanisZeratul I hope that it worked out like this.

Comment: kindly check my answer below, it might be helpful for you also. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly allow me to answer my own question...

This setting worked for me in this case:

API URL Request: localhost:9200/myindex/_mapping/mydoctype

HTTP Body:

```
{
    "mydoctype" : {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties" : {
            "theNumber" : {"type" : "integer"},
            "theString" : {"type" : "string"},
            "stash":  {
                    "type":     "object",
                    "dynamic":  false 
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried adding this object:

```
{
    "theNumber" : 5.55555,
    "theString" : 5,
    "fiefoe" : "fiefoe"
}
```

I got this response:

```
{
  "error": "StrictDynamicMappingException[mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [fiefoe] within [mydoctype] is not allowed]",
  "status": 400
}
```

Thanks =)!

P.S.
Reference:
   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/dynamic-mapping.html